# UIViewController not being presented due to another being recently dismissed

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I have one view controller `MainViewController` which (through buttons) allows the user to present/dismiss another `InventoryViewController` modally.

A third view controller `CallViewcontroller` is then presented programmatically from `MainViewController` at specific timed intervals. Before this happens, `InventoryViewController` is dismissed.

If `InventoryViewController` is never presented, `CallViewController` is presented without any problems.

If `InventoryViewController` is visible/present when `CallViewController` is launched, there also don't seem to be any issues.

But if `InventoryViewController` is presented then manually dismissed by the user, at any point, when `CallViewController` is presented the app partially freezes and the console throws an error -

```
Warning: Attempt to present <CallViewController: 0x17e31bb0> on <MainViewController: 0x18d3fc00> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

Code to launch `InventoryViewController` from `MainViewController`:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueToInventoryView" sender:self];
```

Code to dismiss `InventoryViewController` from a button from within `MainViewController`:

```
[self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Code to dismiss `InventoryViewController` programmatically from `MainViewController` just before `CallViewController` is presented:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
```

(I also use a timer to delay the method that presents `CallViewController` to make sure `InventoryViewController` has been properly dismissed)

I'm guessing that the error is saying that I can't present a modal from `MainViewController` because it isn't at the top of the stack, suggesting that `InventoryViewController` hasn't been properly dismissed.

Originally my code was written for iOS7, now the BaseSDK is iOS9 ( I am returning to this project and iOS programming generally after a year). As far as I am aware, this problem didn't occur before. So is this being caused by changes brought on by iOS8/9, or is there something else happening here?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, I had a flag in `MainViewController` for checking if `InventoryViewController` had been dismissed, which wasn't being set correctly. This was causing `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil]` to be called twice, and the second time round it was actually dismissing `MainViewController`, by sending the call to it's parent!

So the fact that [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil] can be called on both the presenting and presented view controller is perhaps something to watch out for.

The code outlined above all seems to work fine in iOS8/9